# Saving game in local storage results in [object Object] and undefined

Tags: javascript, save, local-storage, loading

`model` is an object that contains every single variable in my code in the form of arrays and objects. I want to save a snapshot of the values within whenever I use the saveGame function, and then redefine it to that snapshot whenever I use the loadGame function. However, when I use loadGame(), it returns [object Object], and then every single piece of information within becomes undefined. What gives?

```js
function saveGame() {
    localStorage.setItem('model', model);
}
function loadGame() {
    model = localStorage.getItem('model');
    updateView();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#description), keys and values stored in `localStorage` are always in UTF-16 [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) format.

Therefore you can't store an object inside of a `localStorage`. Since it only accepts strings. The `[object Object]` you mentioned is a string representation of an object which it automatically creates using the default `Object.toString()` method.

To convert an object into a string representation and preserve the variables. You could serialize the object into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`. And later deserialize it using `JSON.parse()` to convert it back into an object.

```js
function saveGame() {
    localStorage.setItem('model', JSON.stringify(model));
}
function loadGame() {
    model = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('model'));
    updateView();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work perfectly. However, now it doesn't even use that model anymore after I load it. It works just fine when I set specific values from within the model, but apparently not when I store and load the entire model. It's weird. The variables that my updateView() function calls don't change based on what I just set model to in loadGame().

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. I've added deeper explanation to my answer. Can't help you more because I don't have the context. If you have encountered different problem, you might consider asking another question on SO. After doing some research and trying to fix the issue yourself obviously. Good luck.